# custom error html page not displayed when servlet throws user defined exception

Tags: servlets

I am a newbie to jsp and servlets. I have an error.html page which I would like to get displayed when my servlet throws a user defined exception, but I get a 500 inetrnal server error. The error setup works correctly when I do a response.sendError.. Could you please help me out? The code is given below..

```
if ((username != null) && (username.length() > 0)) {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response");

    if (dispatcher != null) {
       dispatcher.include(request, response);
    }
 } 
 //If user does not enter anything, throw a custom exception
 else {
    //response.sendError(500, "You did not enter your name");
    throw new NameNotEnteredException();
 }
```

I have attached my web.xml error config below:

```
 <error-page>
    <exception-type>exceptions.NameNotEnteredException</exception-type>
    <location>/NameNotEnteredError.html</location>
</error-page>
```

I have attached the stack trace by glassfish server: I hope this is the stack trace you
are asking for? otherwise please tell me how to generate the stack trace ?

===========================start of stack trace=================================
INFO: hello_servlet_errorhandling was successfully deployed in 359 milliseconds.
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[GreetingServlet2]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet GreetingServlet2 threw exception exceptions.NameNotEnteredException
    at servlets.GreetingServlet2.doGet(GreetingServlet2.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

==========================end of stack trace=============================================

Comment: how did you set your `error-page` in your `web.xml`?

Comment: show your error page configuration in web.xml

Comment: I have attached my web.xml error page configuration below

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the "internal server error" page which you got?

Comment: I find it weird that your symptoms describe exactly the opposite of the expected behaviour. Are you 100% certain that you're running the code which you think you're running? To be sure, rebuild, redeploy and restart after the changing between throwing the exception or sending the response error. By the way, this is definitely not the proper way of handling client input validation errors, but that's a whole story apart.

Comment: I have rebuilt, redeployed.. same result

Comment: Do you have any filters in your webapp? Maybe one of them is changing the error/exception handling.

Comment: solved. internet explorer was the problem. works fine with firefox. while looking at this issue was having same error setup problem with jsps too which made me explore different options. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I have same issue. Code sample is coming from "The Java EE 7 Tutorial" (hello2) when trying to implement error page based on exception-type. Basically exception reported to console/log, no redirect to error page. Used Glassfish 4.1, browser - Google Chrome 39.
Details - "6.5.3.1 To Set Up Error Mapping Using NetBeans IDE" (9.2)